# How can I horizontally scroll div by mouse wheel, locking the body scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I did make my div to horizontally scroll. But it does not scroll with mouse wheel. I tried 'react-scroll-horizontal' package but its body lock option did not work for me, and it does not have wheel option. Also, I want to lock my document body scroll until the div is completely scrolled to its end. So I want to control and know my div scroll state.

```
handleDivScroll = (e) => {
    const container = document.getElementsByClassName("labels-box");
    console.log(container.scrollTop)
    console.log(container.scrollLeft)
}

<div className="labels-box">
    {this.handleDivScroll}
    <img className="labels" src={LabelImg} alt="" />
    <img className="labels" src={LabelImg} alt="" />
    <img className="labels" src={LabelImg} alt="" />
    <img className="labels" src={LabelImg} alt="" />                              
</div>
```

this does not show console message well.

```
.labels-box {
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

this makes the div scroll horizontally but mouse wheel does not work.

Also, I tried

```
transform: rotate(-90deg); //for .labels-box
transform: rotate(90deg); //for .labels
```

but mouse wheel not worked.

Comment: @SteveK this is exactly what I'm looking for!!

Comment: Horizontal scrolling by default works with Shift + Mousewheel. That's also exactly what I would expect as a user. I would not recommend implementing anything other than this standard behaviour.

Comment: @connexo Okay, thanks but I have to do that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with scrollmagic.  You can see the scrollmagic library [Here](http://scrollmagic.io/) and they have a react package that you can install with npm or yarn [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scrollmagic).  I pushed the example I commented on to github so you can just download the repository and customize to your liking [Here](https://github.com/SteveKanger/react-scrollmagic-horizontal-scrolling-section).  The basic idea behind this is to pin a section to the window and then move the section inside horizontally while scrolling until finished and then proceed on scrolling normally down the site.  So your component would look something like the following:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Controller, Scene } from 'react-scrollmagic';
import { Tween, Timeline } from 'react-gsap';

const SlideContainer = () => {
  const [state] = useState({
    sections: [
      { id: 1, imgSrc: 'https://placehold.it/1920x1080' },
      { id: 2, imgSrc: 'https://placehold.it/1920x1080' },
      { id: 3, imgSrc: 'https://placehold.it/1920x1080' },
      { id: 4, imgSrc: 'https://placehold.it/1920x1080' }
    ]
  });

  const tweenPercentage = 100 - 100 / state.sections.length;

  return (
    <Controller>
      <Scene triggerHook="onLeave" duration={2000} pin>
        {progress => (
          <div className="pin-container" style={styles.pinContainer}>
            <Timeline totalProgress={progress} paused>
              <Tween from={{ x: '0%' }} to={{ x: '-' + tweenPercentage + '%' }}>
                <div
                  className="slide-container"
                  style={{
                    ...styles.slideContainer,
                    width: state.sections.length + '00%'
                  }}
                >
                  {state.sections.map(section => (
                    <div
                      className="panel"
                      key={section.id}
                      style={styles.panel}
                    >
                      <div
                        style={{
                          background: 'url(' + section.imgSrc + ')',
                          backgroundSize: 'cover',
                          backgroundPosition: 'center',
                          width: '100%',
                          height: '100%'
                        }}
                      />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Tween>
            </Timeline>
          </div>
        )}
      </Scene>
    </Controller>
  );
};

const styles = {
  normalSection: {
    background: '#282c34',
    height: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  pinContainer: {
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100%',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },
  slideContainer: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex'
  },
  panel: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: '40px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
};

export default SlideContainer;
```

In the example I just am looping through objects I placed in the state and then I have a few equations to automatically set div widths but you can customize it to your liking fairly easily.  Place divs inside of the `.slide-container` and make sure to set the slide containers width to your liking.  If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but implementing this does not lock the window body scroll. And how can I implement this inside the div ?

Comment: There is no reason with this to lock the body.  The idea is to pin a container to the top of the window and then scroll that pin containers child div horizontally until you have scrolled past the horizontal content and then continue scrolling normally.  I have edited the github to show this a little better.  So download the github and run it and you can see what i'm talking about.  As far as implementing it in your div you will use the `.pin-container` as the div that will pin to the top and the `.scoll-container` will horizontally scroll inside the `.pin-container` until...

Comment: ... the the tween setting you have set has ended and then you can scroll normally down the site.  So there will be no reason to lock the body's scroll function because you will use the native scroll function to scroll the horizontal content.  Maybe I am not understanding what you are trying to achieve because your question was kind of vague that is why I originally posted a comment with an example.  But download the revised github and run it and if you still have questions let me know.  There is two different examples in the github so scroll all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Okay, I will ask more detail next time. I downloaded your git code and tried it. You really understood well what I'm trying to. This is exactly what I want!!!  I really appreciate for your detail and kind answer :)

Comment: I will study deeper, looking your code. Are you okay if I use this for my own use?????

Comment: Ya you can use it that's fine

Comment: Hello...... can I make that Topsection container to be pinned on vertical center using this code? I keep trying but cannot do that. sorry for asking again

Comment: You can move the scene up and down by using the triggerhook settings on the Scene.  I think triggerhook={0.25} would probably center it but not sure.  The big issue you are going to have is that the content above your scene is going to keep scrolling so you are going to have work out an algorithm or some kind of system for pinning the above content as well.  I am pretty busy at the moment but if I have some free time I will try and sit down and work up something here in the next couple of days and get back to you.  In the meantime you can check out the docs I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Maybe too late reply, but you are right. triggerhook is the answer! I struggled with CSS but the answer was here... anyway I really appreciate you for kind answer and code with github. It really helps. Thank you